# How can I create an organization invitation through the Gitub API

Tags: github-api

I'm trying to generate an Organization invite for users that have not yet been added to any Team or Org within our GitHub Enterprise installation.

I've followed the instructions in the doc:

https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#create-organization-invitation

and added the Accept header as required:

application/vnd.github.dazzler-preview+json

and I am an owner of the Org, but I still only receive:

{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.15/v3"
}

when sending the invite.  Is this functionality still supported, or No? Has the Accept header changed?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [GitHub Authentication](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication)

> Requests that require authentication will return 404 Not Found, instead of 403 Forbidden, in some places.
>   This is to prevent the accidental leakage of private repositories to unauthorized users.

So make sure first that the right credentials information have been use for your `POST /orgs/:org/invitations` call.
Try with a `curl -kLv`, just to get more details on the failed operation.

Comment: I'm able to use the same credentials to add a member to a team in the same org, using /teams/:team/memberships/:user, so aside from the Accept header, all the other info is identical. It just seems /orgs/:org/invitations is no longer valid, or has changed since the original API posting.